Recent degredation - extreme slowness
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on an AMD Ryzen 7 processor with Radeon 780M graphics. For the past week, I've had a problem where the display refresh rate in GNOME drops to less than one frame per second. Usually this is triggered while watching a youtube video in Firefox while on battery. A reboot is needed to restore performance (logging out and back in will not solve it).
The only change I am aware of are recent Ubuntu updates, including a kernel update: I am running now 6.8.0-51-generic. Processor and memory usage look normal during the slowdown.
Any idea what could be causing this?
